# Business Central AL Event : Create a "warehouse shipping" on "Sale order"

Tags: dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I need to modify a "Warehouse Shipping Order"  after is created from a "Sale Order".

[image]

I expected to find the "OnAfterShippingOrderCreate" event with a "Sale Order Header"  as input but I don't find that.

There is a event to intercept after the "Warehouse Shipping Order" is created?

Business Central il version 21

Thanks
LSo

Answer (score 0):

have a look into the `report 5753 "Get Source Documents"`, which is called by the `codeunit 5752 "Get Source Doc. Outbound"`. In the `procedure CreateShptHeader()` the event publisher `OnAfterCreateShptHeader` is called after the warehouse shipment header is inserted:

```
    ...
    WhseShptHeader.Insert(true);
    ...

    OnAfterCreateShptHeader(WhseShptHeader, "Warehouse Request", "Sales Line");
end;

...

[EventSubscriber(ObjectType::Report, Report::"Get Source Documents", 'OnAfterCreateShptHeader', '', false, false)]
local procedure OnAfterCreateShptHeader(var WarehouseShipmentHeader: Record "Warehouse Shipment Header"; WarehouseRequest: Record "Warehouse Request"; SalesLine: Record "Sales Line");
begin
end;
```

Here's an example:

```
[EventSubscriber(ObjectType::Report, Report::"Get Source Documents", 'OnAfterCreateShptHeader', '', false, false)]
local procedure OnAfterCreateShptHeader(var WarehouseShipmentHeader: Record "Warehouse Shipment Header"; WarehouseRequest: Record "Warehouse Request"; SalesLine: Record "Sales Line");
var
    SalesHeader: Record "Sales Header";
begin
    if SalesHeader.Get(Enum::"Sales Document Type"::Order, SalesLine."Document No.") then begin
        // add business logic here
    end;
end;
```

If this is not the event you are looking for, you can surely find another one in the `Get Source Documents` codeunit. The `trigger OnPostDataItem()` of the `"Warehouse Request"` dataitem might also be worth a look.

If you find this answer helpful, please mark the question as answered.

/Christian